# Is there a link checker for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, hyperlink

I'm looking for a program, feature or timerjob that checks links on SharePoint 2010 Publishing-Sites and Hyperlink-Lists if they are alive.

The Out-of-the-box link scanner of SharePoint checks only internal links. I need one that checks external links, too.

I tried non SharePoint link checkers, but they won't work with the SharePoint authentification. I found [SharePoint Link Checker](http://splinkchecker.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex and it sounds about right, but [seems to work only with SharePoint 2007](http://splinkchecker.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=216162).

Any tools I should check out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used parts from the SharePoint Link Checker project to build my own link checker for SharePoint. If you tell me how to contact you, I can send you sources.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I'm still looking for a complete solution for a company or community. But maybe you can mail me your project, just in case: sp-at-hinek.de

Answer (score 1):

If this project is on Codeplex, then it wouldn't take a huge amount of work to get it work with SP 2010, as the API hasn't changed massively. As a quick check, I'd pull the code and compile against SP2010 - I'm not saying it will work, but it could be worth a shot.

Apart from that I'd say you're looking at a custom solution.

Best of luck,
Shane

Comment: Ok, migrating the project myself was always my last trump. But I would like to use a solution with a community or a company behind it. Creating a new solution (or modifying the CodePley project) should be the last option, and I think to check for broken links is a very common problem...

Comment: I agree, it is a common enough request - however SP2010 is very young (I'm still getting a tumbleweed for most of my issues when I use google!) - I'm sure that the codeplex project will eventually be updated/migrated.

Anyway best of luck with it, if I come across anything I will post here.

Shane

Comment: Thanks, I hope there will be other answers with tools. I'm not sure if I should have posted this question on serverfault.com ...

Answer (score 0):

Is the website available online? With it's "custom" login system? Because I often get sharepoint questions for my software, but I can't help them really since I don't have SharePoint. My link checker supports basic auth + https/post, but I guess sharepoint is not using any of those... But what then? :)

If I can actually test again a login protected sharepoint website that is online. Then *please* PM/email/post it :)